# Alam fire only recently sending values

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-alarms

I'm using two  buttons like btn1 and btn2,and also I'm using time-picker dialog for both buttons. btn1 select 7.50 am and btn2 select 8.10am, if i send 7.50am  value via Bluetooth then alarm fire,if i send 8.10 am value then alarm fire only 8.10 am ,it override the first sending value.I want to fire alarm for both values at exact time,how to solve this problem please help me....

Answer (score 0):

When setting alarm pass a unique id for each alarm you set in the second parameter of request code

```
 PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, requestCode, intent, 0);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```